# retrieve top sellers from single table in mysql.?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to retrieve data from mysql of my client affiliated bestsellers for that i have table which store every order id and it's seller id also with amount of it, 
table contains same name sellers so now how can i get select data in sequence of first show seller who num of rows are more and keep do it in desc order.

```
select DISTINCT MAX(reseller_id) FROM affilated_comission
```

here is mysql query i am using which is only showing one result i want it also shows who are maximum after top 1.

Comment: hey please check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: where did i done mistake

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
SELECT 
    seller_id, 
    COUNT(volume) AS volume 
FROM 
    table 
GROUP BY 
    seller_id 
HAVING 
    COUNT(volume) >= 10 
ORDER BY 
    volume DESC
```

Comment: i am getting who have sell more by using SELECT MAX(seller_id) from table. but it only shows one i want it shows all but first who is on top then one by one keep show